# UIBezierPath subtraction from another UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

I am making an app that allows the user to draw on the screen with his finger in different colors.  The drawings are drawn with UIBezierPaths but I need an eraser.  I did have an eraser that was just a path with the background image as the color but this method causes memory issues.  I would like to delete the points from any path that is drawn on when eraser is selected.

Unfortunately UIBezierPath doesn't have a subtraction function so I want to make my own.  So if eraser is selected, it will look at all the points that should be erased and see if any of the existing paths contain those points, then subdivide the path leaving a blank spot.  But it should be able to see how many points in a row to delete not do it one at a time.  In theory it makes sense but I'm having trouble getting started on the implementation.

Anyone have any guidance to set me on the right 'path'?

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex.  Is there a reason that you can't rasterize the paths instead (i.e. draw them to a CGBitmapContext and just draw the context in drawRect)?  That will get rid of your memory issue (and use kCGBlendModeClear instead of a stroke with the same color as the BG to erase).  Your method will get slow very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon first glance, it appears that you could do hit detection on a UIBezierPath by simply using `containsPoint:`.  That works fine if you want to determine whether the point is contained in the **fill** of a UIBezierPath, but it does not work for determining whether only the **stroke** of the UIBezierPath intersects the point.  Detecting whether or not a given point is in the stroke of a UIBezierPath can be done as described in the "Doing Hit-Detection on a Path" section at the bottom of [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html).  Actually, the code sample they give could be used either way.  The basic idea is that you have to use the Core Graphics method [CGContextPathContainsPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextPathContainsPoint).

Depending on how large the eraser brush is, you will probably want to check several different points on the edge of the brush circle to see if they intersect the curve, and you'll probably have to iterate through your UIBezierPaths until you get a hit.  You should be able to optimize the search by using the `bounds` of the UIBezierPath.

After you detect that a point intersects a UIBezierPath, you must do the actual split of the path.  There appears to be a good outline of the algorithm in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997476/1144176).  The main idea there is to use [De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) to perform the subdivision of the curve.  There are various implementations of the algorithm that you should be able to find with a quick search, including some in C++.