# iOS drawRect, finding points on a curve

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, uibezierpath

I will draw a curve similar to the red curve in the illustration below (can be a bezier or whatever is most convenient for my purposes I think). I would like to find points on the curve (blue dots in the illo). The points would most likely be divisions of equal parts of the length of the curve.

Can I find these points? I am not seeing a solution in the docs as of yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997476/1124373) covers segmentation of a Bezier curve using the de Casteljau algorithm. You already have your parameterized values along the curve for segmentation.

(If you follow the [link](http://www.caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/bezierintro.html) referenced in the answer make sure you have java enabled in your browser, so you can view the example visualisations).