# UIBezierPath - array of points from path?

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, cgpath

I have a UIBezierPath.

I wish to get an array of all the points in the path.

Is that possible?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: There is a `UIBezierPath` and a `CGPath` but no `CGPath`. Please restate your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051760/getting-a-list-of-points-from-a-uibezierpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `UIBezierPath` nor `CGPath` have a method to obtain their points. This makes sense because the paths can be created with methods that are not simple points.

As @daveMac mentions in a comment there is a work-around:

```
void CGPathApply (
   CGPathRef path,
   void *info,
   CGPathApplierFunction function
);
```

For each element in the specified path, Quartz calls the applier function, which can examine (but not modify) the element.

Comment: What about CGPathApply? I do the very thing the OP is asking quite often when I need to dissect a path.