# UIBezierPath find cross points / get all points

Tags: uibezierpath

Is there any way to get all crossing points of lines created using UIBezierPaths?
I could also imagine a solution where I get all points inside the UIBezierPath and check them one after the other...

Thanks, kind regards, Julian

Comment: You could use CGPathApply() as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051760/getting-a-list-of-points-from-a-uibezierpath

Comment: Check My Answer here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153223/how-to-crop-the-image-using-uibezierpath/15353848#15353848>

Answer (score 1):

I get all the points of a UIBezierpath on this sample code, there is a mathematical approach for it and you need to know key points of the curve , this example probably will help you ,

you can take a look at :

- [Curvy UISlider](https://github.com/milianoo/CurvySlider)

I will try to update it soon.