# Get UIBezierPath point.y with set point.x iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibezierpath

I have a [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/) that I need to get point y when I set point x

thanks

Comment: The question is more than unclear. You need to get "point y" of what exactly? What do you mean by "point x" and "point y"? Are you talking about the x and y coordinates of one point or two different points? Please describe your problem.

Comment: yes, i mean how can i get y coordinate of my path in x coordinate, like http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/iossimulatorscreenshoto.png/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to interpolate between the points. To access the points, it would be easiest to have them stored into an `NSMutableArray`. Create this array and add all CGPoints while you add them to your `UIBezierPath` in your drawing routine. If this is not possible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051760/getting-a-list-of-points-from-a-uibezierpath) on how to extract points from a `UIBezierPath`. See code below on how to achieve what you want:

```
-(float)getYValueFromArray:(NSArray*)a atXValue:(float)x
{
    NSValue *v1, *v2;
    float x1, x2, y1, y2;

    // iterate through all points
    for(int i=0; i<([a count]-1); i++)
    {
        // get current and next point
        v1 = [a objectAtIndex:i];
        v2 = [a objectAtIndex:i+1];

        // return if value matches v1.x or v2.x
        if(x==[v1 CGPointValue].x) return [v1 CGPointValue].y;
        if(x==[v2 CGPointValue].x) return [v2 CGPointValue].y;

        // if x is between v1.x and v2.x calculate interpolated value
        if((x>[v1 CGPointValue].x) && (x<[v2 CGPointValue].x))
        {
            x1 = [v1 CGPointValue].x;
            x2 = [v2 CGPointValue].x;
            y1 = [v1 CGPointValue].y;
            y2 = [v2 CGPointValue].y;
            return (x-x1)/(x2-x1)*(y2-y1) + y1;
        }
    }

    // should never reach this point
    return -1;
}

-(void)test
{
    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake( 0, 10)]];
    [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10,  5)]];
    [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(15, 20)]];
    [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(20, 30)]];
    [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(35, 50)]];
    [a addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(50,  0)]];

    float y = [self getYValueFromArray:a atXValue:22.5];
    NSLog(@"Y value at X=22.5 is %.2f", y);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but he didn't ask for curves. His initial question was very vague and probably impossible to answer. But from his first comment and the picture link you see a chart consisting of lines, that's why I suggested this solution.

Comment: you're Great @nullp01nter, it really helped me, nice idea, unfortunately my reputation isn't enough to vote up your answer, so could you vote up my question to vote up your answer, sorry its a little funny :)

Comment: Nice to hear I could help. BTW, I voted up your comment, now your reputation is high enough. If you care, you could now vote up, too :)

Comment: @JonathanCichon To start with curves you could check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16756481/4244501).

Answer (score 1):

@nullp01nter Thanks for your nice answer. Exactly what i needed! :)
Here is my Swift version of it as Extension for Arrays with PointXYs:

```
protocol PointXY {
    var x : CGFloat { get set }
    var y : CGFloat { get set }
}

extension CGPoint: PointXY { }

extension Array where Element: PointXY {
    func getYValue(forX x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat? {
        for index in 0..<(self.count - 1) {
            let p1 = self[index]
            let p2 = self[index + 1]
            // return p.y if a p.x matches x
            if x == p1.x { return p1.y }
            if x == p2.x { return p2.y }
            // if x is between p1.x and p2.x calculate interpolated value
            if x > p1.x && x < p2.x {
                let x1 = p1.x
                let x2 = p2.x
                let y1 = p1.y
                let y2 = p2.y
                return (x - x1) / (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1) + y1
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```