# Get each and every cgpoint(x,y) coordinates using UIBezierPath like all pixel(x,y)

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I just draw path using UIBezierPath and i would like to get each and every CGPoint that come under UIBezierPath. 
I try with following code

```
func forEach( body: [![enter image description here][1]][1]@escaping @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void) {
    typealias Body = @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void
    let callback: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutableRawPointer, UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>) -> Void = { (info, element) in
        let body = unsafeBitCast(info, to: Body.self)
        body(element.pointee)
    }
    //print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: body))
    let unsafeBody = unsafeBitCast(body, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
    self.apply(info: unsafeBody, function: unsafeBitCast(callback, to: CGPathApplierFunction.self))
}

func getPathElementsPoints() -> [CGPoint] {
    var arrayPoints : [CGPoint]! = [CGPoint]()
    self.forEach { element in
        switch (element.type) {
        case CGPathElementType.moveToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
        case .addLineToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
        case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[1])
        case .addCurveToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[1])
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[2])
        default: break
        }
    }
    return arrayPoints
}
func getPathElementsPointsAndTypes() -> ([CGPoint],[CGPathElementType]) {
    var arrayPoints : [CGPoint]! = [CGPoint]()
    var arrayTypes : [CGPathElementType]! = [CGPathElementType]()
    self.forEach { element in
        switch (element.type) {

        case CGPathElementType.moveToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
            arrayTypes.append(element.type)
        case .addLineToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
            arrayTypes.append(element.type)
        case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[1])
            arrayTypes.append(element.type)
            arrayTypes.append(element.type)
        case .addCurveToPoint:
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[0])
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[1])
            arrayPoints.append(element.points[2])
            arrayTypes.append(element.type)
            arrayTypes.append(element.type)
            arrayTypes.append(element.type)
        default: break
        }
    }
    return (arrayPoints,arrayTypes)
}
```

I am able to get points using this above code with CGPoint, but it's give only that control point.

Any one suggest for me how can i get all points

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple (maybe inaccurate depending on the use case) way to do this would be:

```
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10))

    let pathBounds = bezierPath.bounds
    let minX = Int(pathBounds.minX)
    let maxX = Int(pathBounds.maxX)
    let minY = Int(pathBounds.minY)
    let maxY = Int(pathBounds.maxY)

    var allPoints: [CGPoint] = []
    var pathPoints: [CGPoint] = []

    for x in minX...maxX {
        for y in minY...maxY {

            let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y))
            allPoints.append(point)

            if bezierPath.contains(point) {
                pathPoints.append(point)
            }
        }
    }

    print("All Points: \(allPoints.count)")
    print("Path Points: \(pathPoints.count)")
```

For me this prints

```
All Points: 6561 
Path Points: 5025
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks to identify the (x, y) coordinates, but here I am getting only some points

Like I have one speed curve chart that speed curve chart have one original path curve so that path curve I want to (x, y)coordinates that comes under UIBezierPath

Comment: Can you please let me know about that path coordinates come under UIBezierPath with curve line, just need to curve line x,y coordinates

Comment: for this example, I am getting value like x: 0.0, y:183.0 again x:1.0, y: 182.0 like this but I want with floating point also like 24.75, 56.25 etc...