# Find point at index in UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cgpoint

I have a path that contains a list of points, like so:

```
<UIBezierPath: 0x1780a7260; <MoveTo {33, 100}>,
 <LineTo {33, 100}>,
 <LineTo {99, 100}>,
 <LineTo {165, 400}>,
 <LineTo {231, 400}>,
 <LineTo {297, 0}>,
 <LineTo {363, 400}>,
 <LineTo {429, 400}>,
 <LineTo {495, 200}>,
 <LineTo {561, 0}>,
 <LineTo {627, 100}>,
 <LineTo {693, 0}>,
 <LineTo {759, 200}>
```

I want to be able to access, examples, the second point in that list, almost like you would be able to access an array object like `[path pointAtIndex:1];`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Examine the path, call CGPathApply, and read the CGPathElements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051760/getting-a-list-of-points-from-a-uibezierpath