# How to change rect of an object moving with bezier path in objective c

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to change rect with bezier path movement:

```m
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [self createArcPath].CGPath;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// btn.frame = CGRectMake(326, 174, 64, 64);
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Volleyball_Ball.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

// car = [CALayer layer];
// car.frame = CGRectMake(326, 174, 48, 48);
// car.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"1453303583_circle_blue.png"].CGImage);
// [self.view.layer addSublayer:car];

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.path = [self createArcPath].CGPath;
anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
anim.delegate = self;
anim.repeatCount = 1;
anim.duration = 3.0;
[btn.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"race"];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 174, 64, 64);
```

I would like to get `CGRECT` for every point during movement and store into and array, Its already moving in a circle but I need to get `CGRECT` for every Point.

Comment: and the current problem is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I animate the movement of a view or image along a curved path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path)

Comment: I would like to get rect for every point during movement and store into and array

Comment: Its already moving in a circle but i need to get CGRECT for every Point

Comment: You may want to clarify your question using this discussion in the comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5714872/3501300 take a look at this answer, it may help