# Truncate a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, animation, uibezierpath, bezier, ios-animations

I'm trying to create a sort of progress bar class that fills along a `UIBezierPath` as it progresses. I need to stroke a `UIBezierPath` with a controlled animation.

I think I could implement this if I could truncate the path to a precise portion of its original length. Is this possible? Is there another method I can use to precisely control the animated stroking of a path?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3051760/4414003), but the answer seems to address finding the points at the beginning and end of each element. I'd need to get a list of points at a pixel-by-pixel level for a list of points to be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I'm looking for the `strokeEnd` property.

Comment: Yup—make a CAShapeLayer, give it your bezier path’s `CGPath`, set a stroke color, and adjust `strokeEnd` from 0 to 1.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I actually know nothing about iOS, I'm struggling through iOS by trying to extend the `ui` wrapper that comes with the Pythonista app. I'm trying to figure out which already-implemented Python classes are equivalent to which iOS things, and I'm kind of struggling. I think I'm getting it, though :D