# Is it possible to get UIBezierPath current control points after path transformation?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am working on creating a way for a user to move polygons on screen and change their shape by dragging their corner vertices. I then need to be able to re-draw those modified polygons on other devices - so I need to be able to get final positions of all vertices for all polygons on screen.

This is what I am currently doing:

I draw polygons using `UIBezierPath` for each shape in the override of the `drawRect` function. I then allow user to drag them around the screen by applying `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` function and the `x` and `y` coordinate deltas in `touchedMoved` function override. I have the initial control points from which initial polygons are drawn (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051760/how-to-get-a-list-of-points-from-a-uibezierpath)). But once a path instance is moved on screen, those values don't change - so I am only able to get initial values.

Is there something built - in in the `Core Graphics` framework that will allow me to grab a set of current control points in a `UIBezierPath` instance? I am trying to avoid keeping track of those points manually. I will consider using other ways to draw if:

- there is a built - in way to detect if a point lies within that polygon (such as `UIBezierPath#contains` method
- A way to easily introduce constraints so user can't move a polygon out of bounds of the superview (I need the whole polygon to be visible)
- A way to grab all points easily when user is done
- Everything can run under 60fps on iPhone 5.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As you're only applying the transform to the view/layer, to get the transformed control points from the path, simply apply that same transform to the path, and then fetch the control points. Something like:

```
UIBezierPath* copiedPath = [myPath copy];
[copiedPath applyTransform:[view transform]];
[self yourExistingMethodToFetchPointsFromPath:copiedPath];
```

The way that you're currently pulling out points from a path is unfortunately at the only API available for re-fetching points from an input UIBezierPath. However - you might be interested in a library I wrote to make working with Bezier path's much simpler: [PerformanceBezier](https://github.com/adamwulf/PerformanceBezier). This library makes it significantly easier to get the points from a path:

```
for(NSInteger i=0;i<[path elementCount];i++){
    CGPathElement element = [path elementAtIndex:n];
    // now you know the element.type and the element.points
}
```

In addition to adding functionality to make paths easier to work with, it also adds a caching layer on top of the existing API to make the performance hit of working with paths much much smaller. Depending on how much CPU time you're spending on UIBezierPath methods, this library will make a significant improvement. I saw [between 2x and 10x improvement](http://blog.getlooseleaf.com/post/110511009139/improving-uibezierpath-performance-and-api), depending on the operations I was using.