# Convert UIBezierPath to PKStrokePath swift

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, pencilkit

Is there a way to convert UIBezierPath to PKStrokePath ?

for example I have these path as UIBezierPath
how can I convert it to PKStrokePath to use it in PKDrawing ?

```
let shape = UIBezierPath()
shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30.2, y: 37.71))
shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 15.65, y: 2.08))
shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2.08, y: 37.33))
shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 23.46, y: 21.21))
shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 8.36, y: 21.02))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` `PKStrokePath` are totally diferrent objects

`UIBezierPath` Can have points, lines, curves and jumps to an other point, while `PKStrokePath` can only have points which will be connected, but they have different parameters, like size, force, etc

So to create `PKStrokePath` we would need to calculate points based on a `UIBezierPath`. Also a single `UIBezierPath` may produce more than one `PKStrokePath`, if path has `move` steps inside

That's a tricky path but possible

As the base I took [Finding the closest point on UIBezierPath](https://andreygordeev.com/2017/03/13/uibezierpath-closest-point/). This article talks about calculating `UIBezierPath` points

While author of this article is taking 100 points for each `UIBezierPath` curve, I took a next step and added binary search idea into the algorithm: I wanted to have points on the curve with distance not greater than `stopDistance`(you can play with this value)

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    func generatePathPoints() -> [[CGPoint]] {
        let points = cgPath.points()
        guard points.count > 0 else {
            return []
        }
        var paths = [[CGPoint]]()
        var pathPoints = [CGPoint]()
        var previousPoint: CGPoint?
        let stopDistance: CGFloat = 10
        for command in points {
            let endPoint = command.point
            defer {
                previousPoint = endPoint
            }
            guard let startPoint = previousPoint else {
                continue
            }
            let pointCalculationFunc: (CGFloat) -> CGPoint
            switch command.type {
            case .addLineToPoint:
                // Line
                pointCalculationFunc = {
                    calculateLinear(t: $0, p1: startPoint, p2: endPoint)
                }
            case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
                pointCalculationFunc = {
                    calculateQuad(t: $0, p1: startPoint, p2: command.controlPoints[0], p3: endPoint)
                }
            case .addCurveToPoint:
                pointCalculationFunc = {
                    calculateCube(t: $0, p1: startPoint, p2: command.controlPoints[0], p3: command.controlPoints[1], p4: endPoint)
                }
            case .closeSubpath:
                previousPoint = nil
                fallthrough
            case .moveToPoint:
                if !pathPoints.isEmpty {
                    paths.append(pathPoints)
                    pathPoints = []
                }
                continue
            @unknown default:
                continue
            }
            
            let initialCurvePoints = [
                CurvePoint(position: 0, cgPointGenerator: pointCalculationFunc),
                CurvePoint(position: 1, cgPointGenerator: pointCalculationFunc),
            ]
            let curvePoints = calculatePoints(
                tRange: 0...1,
                pointCalculationFunc: pointCalculationFunc,
                leftPoint: initialCurvePoints[0].cgPoint,
                stopDistance: stopDistance
            ) + initialCurvePoints
            pathPoints.append(
                contentsOf:
                    curvePoints
                    .sorted { $0.position < $1.position }
                    .map { $0.cgPoint }
            )
            previousPoint = endPoint
        }
        if !pathPoints.isEmpty {
            paths.append(pathPoints)
            pathPoints = []
        }
        return paths
    }
    
    private func calculatePoints(
        tRange: ClosedRange<CGFloat>,
        pointCalculationFunc: (CGFloat) -> CGPoint,
        leftPoint: CGPoint,
        stopDistance: CGFloat
    ) -> [CurvePoint] {
        let middlePoint = CurvePoint(position: (tRange.lowerBound + tRange.upperBound) / 2, cgPointGenerator: pointCalculationFunc)
        if hypot(leftPoint.x - middlePoint.cgPoint.x, leftPoint.y - middlePoint.cgPoint.y) < stopDistance {
            return [middlePoint]
        }
        let leftHalfPoints = calculatePoints(tRange: tRange.lowerBound...middlePoint.position, pointCalculationFunc: pointCalculationFunc, leftPoint: leftPoint, stopDistance: stopDistance)
        let rightHalfPoints = calculatePoints(tRange: middlePoint.position...tRange.upperBound, pointCalculationFunc: pointCalculationFunc, leftPoint: middlePoint.cgPoint, stopDistance: stopDistance)
        return leftHalfPoints + rightHalfPoints + [middlePoint]
    }
}

private struct CurvePoint {
    let position: CGFloat
    let cgPoint: CGPoint
    
    init(position: CGFloat, cgPointGenerator: (CGFloat) -> CGPoint) {
        self.position = position
        self.cgPoint = cgPointGenerator(position)
    }
}

struct PathCommand {
    let type: CGPathElementType
    let point: CGPoint
    let controlPoints: [CGPoint]
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/38743318/1321917
extension CGPath {
    func points() -> [PathCommand] {
        var bezierPoints = [PathCommand]()
        forEachPoint { element in
            guard element.type != .closeSubpath else {
                return
            }
            let numberOfPoints: Int = {
                switch element.type {
                case .moveToPoint, .addLineToPoint: // contains 1 point
                    return 1
                case .addQuadCurveToPoint: // contains 2 points
                    return 2
                case .addCurveToPoint: // contains 3 points
                    return 3
                case .closeSubpath:
                    return 0
                @unknown default:
                    fatalError()
                }
            }()
            var points = [CGPoint]()
            for index in 0..<(numberOfPoints - 1) {
                let point = element.points[index]
                points.append(point)
            }
            let command = PathCommand(type: element.type, point: element.points[numberOfPoints - 1], controlPoints: points)
            bezierPoints.append(command)
        }
        return bezierPoints
    }
    
    private func forEachPoint(body: @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void) {
        typealias Body = @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void
        func callback(_ info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, _ element: UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>) {
            let body = unsafeBitCast(info, to: Body.self)
            body(element.pointee)
        }
        withoutActuallyEscaping(body) { body in
            let unsafeBody = unsafeBitCast(body, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
            apply(info: unsafeBody, function: callback as CGPathApplierFunction)
        }
    }
}

/// Calculates a point at given t value, where t in 0.0...1.0
private func calculateLinear(t: CGFloat, p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let mt = 1 - t
    let x = mt*p1.x + t*p2.x
    let y = mt*p1.y + t*p2.y
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

/// Calculates a point at given t value, where t in 0.0...1.0
private func calculateCube(t: CGFloat, p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint, p3: CGPoint, p4: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let mt = 1 - t
    let mt2 = mt*mt
    let t2 = t*t
    
    let a = mt2*mt
    let b = mt2*t*3
    let c = mt*t2*3
    let d = t*t2
    
    let x = a*p1.x + b*p2.x + c*p3.x + d*p4.x
    let y = a*p1.y + b*p2.y + c*p3.y + d*p4.y
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

/// Calculates a point at given t value, where t in 0.0...1.0
private func calculateQuad(t: CGFloat, p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint, p3: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let mt = 1 - t
    let mt2 = mt*mt
    let t2 = t*t
    
    let a = mt2
    let b = mt*t*2
    let c = t2
    
    let x = a*p1.x + b*p2.x + c*p3.x
    let y = a*p1.y + b*p2.y + c*p3.y
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

And the final step of converting points to list of `PKStrokePath` and a `PKDrawing`

```
let strokePaths = path.generatePathPoints().map { pathPoints in
    PKStrokePath(
        controlPoints: pathPoints.map { pathPoint in
            PKStrokePoint(
                location: pathPoint,
                timeOffset: 0,
                size: .init(width: 5, height: 5),
                opacity: 1,
                force: 1,
                azimuth: 0,
                altitude: 0
            )
        },
        creationDate: Date()
    )
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
let drawing = PKDrawing(
    strokes: strokePaths.map { strokePath in
        PKStroke(
            ink: PKInk(.pen, color: UIColor.black),
            path: strokePath
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: You solution work great with curves , thank you

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest capturing the array of arrays of `CGPoint`, e.g.

```swift
let pointArrays = [
    [CGPoint(x: 30.2, y: 37.71), CGPoint(x: 15.65, y: 2.08), CGPoint(x: 2.08, y: 37.33)], 
    [CGPoint(x: 23.46, y: 21.21), CGPoint(x: 8.36, y: 21.02)]
]
```

From that, you could create the appropriate `UIBezierPath` or `PKStrokePath`, respectively.

For example:

```swift
let path = UIBezierPath()
for stroke in pointArrays where pointArrays.count > 1 {
    path.move(to: stroke.first!)
    for point in stroke.dropFirst() {
        path.addLine(to: point)
    }
}
```

Will yield (with `lineWidth` of 1 and a red stroke color):

[image]

Whereas with PencilKit,

```swift
let ink = PKInk(.pen, color: .blue)
let strokes = pointArrays.compactMap { stroke -> PKStroke? in
    guard stroke.count > 1 else { return nil }
    let controlPoints = stroke.enumerated().map { index, point in
        PKStrokePoint(location: point, timeOffset: 0.1 * TimeInterval(index), size: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3), opacity: 2, force: 1, azimuth: 0, altitude: 0)
    }
    let path = PKStrokePath(controlPoints: controlPoints, creationDate: Date())
    return PKStroke(ink: ink, path: path)
}
let drawing = PKDrawing(strokes: strokes)
```

Will yield:

[image]

Obviously, as the two drawings illustrate, a series of points in a `UIBezierPath` is not the same as a series of control points in a `PKStrokePath`.

If you want the `PKStrokePath` to match, you should create separate paths for each line segment, e.g.

```swift
let ink = PKInk(.pen, color: .blue)
var strokes: [PKStroke] = []

for points in pointArrays where points.count > 1 {
    let strokePoints = points.enumerated().map { index, point in
        PKStrokePoint(location: point, timeOffset: 0.1 * TimeInterval(index), size: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3), opacity: 2, force: 1, azimuth: 0, altitude: 0)
    }

    var startStrokePoint = strokePoints.first!

    for strokePoint in strokePoints {
        let path = PKStrokePath(controlPoints: [startStrokePoint, strokePoint], creationDate: Date())
        strokes.append(PKStroke(ink: ink, path: path))
        startStrokePoint = strokePoint
    }
}
let drawing = PKDrawing(strokes: strokes)
```

Yielding:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Thank you , but I notice it working perfect with straight lines but if I have curves it will show weird shape

Comment: when there is `addCurve` it won't work , for example `let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 11.458, y: 11.458))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 11.458, y: 125.816))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 97.479, y: 60.973), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 11.458, y: 125.816), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 129.531, y: 94.336))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 41.153999999999996, y: 67.304), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 65.42699999999999, y: 27.61), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 62.344, y: 27.677999999999997))`

Comment: This how the shape should looks like : https://a.cl.ly/kpunmeqG