# How can I get points of UIBezierPath?

Tags: swift, uiimage, draw

I have already A path(UIBezierPath), and I draw copy A path at other UIImage.
I can get last point(path.currentPoint), But I can't get start point.
Search about it, and tried many things but I'm failed.
How can I get start point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051760/how-to-get-a-list-of-points-from-a-uibezierpath